# Transparency bug in the dash

Tags: unity, compiz, unity-dash

I'm using ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop acer aspire 5742zg with an optimus nvdia card (bumblebee is running perfectly) and I have a problem with the transparency in the dash. When I open the dash all the launcher become black without transparency. I tried to select the active blur and static blur with compiz but nothing change !

Comment: Close-voter(s): While this says "bug," there isn't really good info to indicate it is. It may simply be, as [doug's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/272403/22949) suggests, that the opacity settings are wrong. With that said, if you believe we can be reasonably sure this *is* a bug, please go ahead and close-vote, but also comment to provide information about why you think so. **Simon:** If you still *do* think this is a bug, please read [the bug reporting documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) carefully, then report it as a bug. I recommend: `ubuntu-bug $(pidof compiz)`

Comment: Just a note, the OP [has confirmed](http://askubuntu.com/questions/272365/transparency-bug-in-the-dash#comment341797_272403) that Doug's answer works.

Answer (score 2):

Transparency (opacity) of the Dash is set by the `opacity` setting for `Background Color` in the unity plugin settings. (any value above 0 activates the custom background setting

See if you've set it to any value above 0, open compizconfig-settings-manager, (ccsm), & find in the unity plugin settings. If not on 0 then set back to 0

Comment: Yes ! it's working well ! my background colour was set with an opacity of 255 --'
Thank you  :) !

Comment: @Simon If this answer has solved your problem please [accept it](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer).  Thanks!